# iOS: UIView wont stick behind status bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

I want to create a status bar with a black opaque background and white text. To do this I did the following:

1. In my .plist set the "UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance" to "NO"
2. In my .plist set the "UIStatusBarStyle
   LightContent" to "UIStatusBarStyleLightContent"
3. Create an UIView in my storyboard with the following constraints:

[image: Status bar UIView]

Now I have a status bar with white text and an opaque background, like this (Ignore the background picture):
[image: Status Bar]

However when I scroll, the UIView background won't stick underneath the statusbar, for example:

[image: Status bar without a BG]

This probably has to do with the vertical constraint, which should link to the top layout guide instead of the superview, but this constraint is not showing in xcode and I have no idea what else could be wrong.

Comment: Your background image is in a scrollview? Is the background image suppose to be scrollable?

Comment: Yes the background image is in a scrollview, and its supposed to be scrollable

Comment: so you don't want the content to go under the status bar? Thanks for the video. Do you want the status bar to have a solid background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Solved in chat, just needed to put the opaque view in front of the scrollview and not have it as a subview of the scrollview.

You could turn bounces off for the scrollview, but this doesn't look as smooth.[image]

Comment: It doesn't have to do with bounces though, the example I provided does show the bounce effect being used - only as a demo purpose to show that the background statusbar doesn't stick to the actual system status bar. I could also scroll down to the middle of my view, and the status bar would still be non sticky!

Comment: Is your image the full size of your scrollview? How can the top of your image be behind the status bar if it is in a scrollview? Maybe we can continue this in chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow